# Variable field name in JQuery validation rules

Tags: jquery, validation, variables, field

There is a question with the same subject, but it dont have a conclusive answer.

I have a bunch of inputs with variable names generated by an add jquery function, and i need to validate those fields (if they exist).

Can i use the validate plugin with the class instead of the name? or something?

Here is my code:

```
//add function

$(document).ready(function(){   

   var i = $('input').size() +1;

   $('#add').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

$('.table1').before('<table class="new_table">
   '<tr>' +
     '<td colspan="4" class="subTitle_bar">' +
       '<spring:message code="phoneTable" /> '+ i +' '+ 
     '</td>' +
   '</tr>' +

   '<tr>' +
       '<td class="item">' +
          '<spring:message code="phoneNumber"  />' +
          '<span class="required">*</span>' +
       '</td>' +

       '<td colspan="3">' +
          '<input type="text" id="phone1' + i + '" name="phone1' + i + '" class="requiredField phone" />' +
       '</td>' +
   '</tr>');
 i++;
});
```

And the validate:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#contactForm").validate({
        //rules
        rules:{
            phone1:{ required: true },
```

How can i validate the phone, if i dont know his field name yet?

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few ideas, in order of what I think makes sense.
 - Adding required attribute to the inputs.
 - Adding class "required"
 - Adding the rules with js after you make the form.

but in short just add < input id="phone" type="text" name="email" **required** / >

He does that in the first example on page http://validation.bassistance.de/documentation/

I don't know this for sure but maybe you need to call $("#contactForm").validate() after you make the form. ( not sure if it matters or not )

Comment: Thanks a lot, its worked, i need also to validate the type of content, where can i define in the plugin this kind of validation?  like a numeric field: < input id="phone" type="text" name="email" digits / >

Comment: I would not have only numeric since +354ddddddd is valid for phones.
but he does have an example http://validation.bassistance.de/phoneUS-method/ but that's US phones. to use that you need http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js in the code you can see few other phone validation rules. so you need to pick one

Answer (score 0):

If you are just needing the field to be required you can just add a class of required to the element you're generating... There are also other options for making fields equal to eachother and whatnot.

> "There are several ways to specify validation rules. Validation methods without parameters can be specified as classes on the element (recommended)" - FROM [Documentation](http://validation.bassistance.de/category/plugin/)